# How do I generate a counter in Swift without refreshing the view

Tags: ios, swift, counter

I want to set a counter that adds 1 every time two certain objects collide. This is my code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var Wall: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var Player: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var CountLabel: UILabel!
var CountNumber : Int!

func PlayerMoving() {
//The code for moving an object.
if (CGRectIntersectsRect(Player.frame, Wall.frame)){
Add()
}}

func Add() {
CountNumber = CountNumber + 1
CountLabel.text = "\(CountNumber)"
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
CountNumber = 0
//Timer for moving the Player
}
```

But after they collide, even though a 1 is added, the scene refreshes. Like if the player moved and hit the wall, the player goes back to where it started originally. I want it to continue with the same speed  in the same direction without going back to the start. Thanks.

Comment: I don't see anything in what you posted that would reset a view.  I think there must be some other code involved.

Comment: I even started a new project and only added the previous coding(including the code for moving the player + a timer) and it still adds a 1 and resets the view.